# How do I use a function within the PUT function in SAS

Tags: types, format, sas, put

How do I print out the format of a variable of interest?
Note i've simplified my example

%let var_ = '1sep2014'
%put | VARTYPE(&var_)

I'd expect this to return the format type in the log but it just returns
| VARTYPE(&1sep2014)

Comment: `VARTYPE` is a data-step function for determining whether a data-step variable is character or numeric type. It doesn't make sense when used in this context, as macro variables do not have a 'type' as such.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't possible as stated.  What you're asking is 'what date format is this in'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way simple way to find a format that matches a string. As mjsqu says the function `vartype` does not do what you are hoping.

However, if you wish to use a datastep function within a macro variable assignment or `%put` statement you can use `%sysfunc()` macro function.

Code:

```
/* Assignment of a string to a macro variable*/
/* SAS date literal "DDMMYYYY"d will be automatically evaluated later */
%let v1 = "01sep2014"d;
%put &v1;

/* Use off a datastep function in an assignment, evaluates date literal as number */
%let v2 = %sysfunc(putn(&v1, date9.));
%put &v2;

/* Use of a datastep function in a %put statement */
%put %sysfunc(putn(&v1, yymmdd10.));
```

Output:

```
"01sep2014"d
01SEP2014
2014-09-01
```